# What are some sources I could use to get to a decent level to be able to analyze advanced classical pieces?

Tags: theory, harmony, classical-music, chopin, mozart

I love Mozart, Bach and Beethoven, Chopin and I just want to be able to understand even more by analyzing them. Does anyone know of a good source for me to study to be able to get to a level where I could analyze such advanced piece?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great site for Chopin: http://www.ourchopin.com/

The ***Work List*** on the side shows his works and is organized by type of piece (etude, bolero, sonata etc.) There is an analysis on each piece.

I find the Etude Magazine kind of useful as it provides insight to the musician, it is a little difficult to navigate though the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a great deal of excellent material here:

[***Robert Greenberg,PhD***](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=robert%20greenberg)

[***How to Listen to and Understand Great Music, 3rd Edition Audiobook***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DTO6GXE)

[***Robert Greenberg - Beethoven's Piano Sonatas***](http://The%20Great%20Courses:%20Beethoven's%20Piano%20Sonatas)

And **much** more...

Or here - same material, different outlet and more variety of formats (**wait for the sales**):

***[Professor Robert Greenberg, Ph.D.](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/professors/robert-greenberg/)***

> *Dr. Robert Greenberg is Music Historian-in-Residence with San Francisco Performances. A graduate of Princeton University, Professor
>   Greenberg holds a Ph.D. in Music Composition from the University of
>   California, Berkeley.  He has seen his compositions—which include more
>   than 45 works for a wide variety of instrumental and vocal
>   ensembles—performed all over the world, including New York, San
>   Francisco, Chicago, Los Angeles, England, Ireland, Greece, Italy, and
>   the Netherlands. He has served on the faculties of the University of
>   California, Berkeley; California State University, Hayward; and the
>   San Francisco Conservatory of Music, and has lectured for some of the
>   most prestigious musical and arts organizations in the United States,
>   including the San Francisco Symphony, the Lincoln Center for the
>   Performing Arts, the Van Cliburn Foundation, and the Chicago Symphony.
>   For The Great Courses, he has recorded more than 500 lectures on a
>   range of composers and classical music genres. Professor Greenberg is
>   a Steinway Artist. His many other honors include three Nicola de
>   Lorenzo Composition Prizes and a Koussevitzky commission from the
>   Library of Congress. He has been profiled in various major
>   publications, including The Wall Street Journal; Inc. magazine; and
>   the London Times.*

Some have problems with Greenberg's style of delivery, but even if you don't care for it, IMO it's well worth suffering through, because of the breadth and scope of his knowledge and his ability to teach and explain.